# Adding an array onto an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i am attempting to make an array:

```
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$catsList[$cat->id] = [$cat->info => $cat->info];
}
```

What i get is a resulting array that only contains the last $cat info.

```
array:2 [▼
  10 => array:1 [▼
    23 => 23
  ]
  9 => array:1 [▼
    11 => 11
  ]
]
```

What i expect to get is:

```
array:2 [▼
  10 => array:1 [▼
    23 => 23
    15 => 15
    12 => 12
  ]
  9 => array:1 [▼
    11 => 11
    24 => 24
  ]
]
```

I guess the syntax is wrong when i'm trying to add a new member and it just overwrites the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    $catsList[$cat->id][$cat->info] = $cat->info;
}
```